# How to send the value of jquery variable to PHP variable in an Array?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm pretty new to Jquery and PHP and I'm trying to get the values of checkboxes in a filter form and sending to php.  I'd like to figure out how to store the PHP variable as an array of all the boxes checked.

My form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="applications[]" <?php echo $selected['applications/food-applications/sugar-reduction/'] ?> id="sugar-reduction" value="applications/food-applications/sugar-reduction/" onchange="$('#app_filter').submit();" >
<input type="checkbox" name="applications[]" <?php echo $selected['applications/food-applications/binding-systems/'] ?> id="binding-systems" value="applications/food-applications/binding-systems/" onchange="$('#app_filter').submit();" >
<input type="checkbox" name="applications[]" <?php echo $selected['applications/food-applications/shelf-life-extension/'] ?> id="shelf-life-extension" value="applications/food-applications/shelf-life-extension/" onchange="$('#app_filter').submit();" >
```

Script:

```
$("#app_filter").submit(function() {
                                
    event.preventDefault();
    
        var checkbox_value = "";
        $(":checked").each(function () {
            var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked");
            if (ischecked) {
                checkbox_value += $(this).val() + ", ";
            }
        });
        console.log(checkbox_value);
        return false;
});
```

With all three boxes checked it is successfully showing the values in the console like this:

```
applications/food-applications/sugar-reduction/, applications/food-applications/binding-systems/, applications/food-applications/shelf-life-extension/,
```

I'd like to store the values in an array and in a PHP variable.  Ideally like this...

```
array(applications/food-applications/sugar-reduction/, applications/food-applications/binding-systems/, applications/food-applications/shelf-life-extension/,)
```

Is that possible?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `$(this).serialize()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this).serialize()` to encode all the form inputs. You can then access them in PHP just as you would with normal form submission.

```js
$("#app_filter").submit(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      type: "post",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

In PHP, `$_POST['applications']` will be an array of all the selected values.

Comment: Thanks for this! However the form is just submitting without the script. I'm grabbing the array with $applist = $_POST['applications']; in my PHP and the form is filtering using that array, but it's refreshing the page.  It's not showing the response in the console either.

Comment: You were missing the `event` parameter so that `event.preventDefault()` would work.

Comment: That seems to be working.  I think i'm running into some issues with the CMS I'm using and the way I've set up the form.  Should the response in the console show the value of the checkboxes?  Right now it's showing the entire page source code.  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: It shows whatever the server script returns. If it returns HTML, that's what you'll see in the console.